# Merging multiple graphs in Python to one graph

Tags: python, plot, graph

Hi im trying to combine 4 graphs together to over lap each other and i am not sure how it is done, the 4 graphs are the plotMultiDays(MergedDataJuly) to plotMultiDays(MergedDataDec)

any help would be great.
Heres the code:

```
MergedDataJuly=MergedData[MergedData.expiration == Date(2016,7,16)]
MergedDataAugust=MergedData[MergedData.expiration == Date(2016,8,20)]
MergedDataSep=MergedData[MergedData.expiration == Date(2016,9,17)]
MergedDataDec=MergedData[MergedData.expiration == Date(2016,12,17)]




plotMultiDays(MergedDataJuly,AgainstMarket='Yes')
plotMultiDays(MergedDataAugust,AgainstMarket='Yes')
plotMultiDays(MergedDataSep,AgainstMarket='Yes')
plotMultiDays(MergedDataDec,AgainstMarket='Yes')

plotMultiDays(MergedDataJuly)
plotMultiDays(MergedDataAugust)
plotMultiDays(MergedDataSep)
plotMultiDays(MergedDataDec)
```